# Twilio ratelimit implementation is not seems working

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Doc: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/service-rate-limit-buckets
The doc is not well explained the bottom queries.

1.created ratelimit with the unique name as 'phone_number'

```
twilio api:verify:v2:services:rate-limits:create \
    --service-sid VAxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --description "Limit verifications by End User phone_number" \
    --unique-name "phone_number"
```

Note: --unique-name i have passed as 'phone_number' static string not actual user phone number..   because '+' not allowed also https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/programmable-rate-limits?code-sample=code-start-a-verification-with-a-rate-limit&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x#selecting-properties-to-rate-limit states it is static text combinations

previously i have used my phone number without + symbol.

2.Step 2

created a bucket with max 4 and duration 60

```
twilio api:verify:v2:services:rate-limits:buckets:create \
    --service-sid VAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --rate-limit-sid RK7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \
    --max 4 \
    --interval 60
```

After this bucket creation i expect to limit the sms sending for all the user based on users phone number ( in 60 second only 4 sms will be send for a user).

But what i can experience that i am receiving all sms which i created message.create().. ratelimit is not seems working..

Q1.is there any issue with the unique name as static text 'phone_number' what i can see is there is no combination of 'phone_number' and
    'phone_number_country_code' ?

Ex:--unique-name "phone_number_country_code_and_phone_number" 
      or unique-name is a parameter that we need to send actual mobile of user?

Q2.if created one bucket with max: 4 duration: 60
    second,  then in 60 second only 4 sms will be send per user ?

Q3.one bucket and one rate limit enough for an application to handle all
    users ?

Q4.if the above step is wrong what is the flow of implementation of this apis?

Q5.3rd api is showing in the doc is send verifications api, is this api is necessary when implementing ratelimits (i assume only create rate-limit and bucket create api are sufficient to enable ratelimit) ?

Q6.if i set bucket max: 4 and duration: 60 , what happen to the 5th sms is scheduled for that user (ex: 5th otp ) is that will deliver in same interval or the next intervel or it will discarded ?

**or
let me know the actual sequential flow of ratelimit apis to accomplish the ratelimit to apply to all users. limit:  4 sms per user for specific 60 second interval.**

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the send verification API with the ratelimit option using the unique-name property of the ratelimit?

```
twilio api:verify:v2:services:verifications:create \
--service-sid VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
--rate-limits "{\"phone_number\": \"1234567890\"}" \
--to to \
--channel channel
```

As I understand it, the purpose of the rate limit is to limit the verification messages. I think the idea is that you create a rate limit and then apply it to a bucket, like you demonstrated. THEN you apply that limit to the verification service using the unique uniqueName and the phone number.

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: this documentation isn't very clear: The custom key-value pairs of Programmable Rate Limits. Keys correspond to unique_name fields defined when creating your Rate Limit. Associated value pairs represent values in the request that you are rate limiting on. You may include multiple Rate Limit values in each request.

Comment: check this https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification

Comment: this the actual response using the optional parameter in post RateLimits{
    "code": 60200,
    "message": "Invalid parameter: 'RateLimits'. Should be a JSON map from string to string.",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/60200",
    "status": 400
}

Comment: any help about this issue?